# How do I get URL query parameters into an object literal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When looking at location.search, what's the best way to take the query parameters and turn them into an object literal? Say I've got a URL that looks like this:

> http://foo.com?nodeId=2&userId=3&sortOrder=name&sequence=asc

What I'd like to wind up with is an object literal that looks like this:

```
var params = {
  nodeId : 2,
  userId : 3,
  sortOrder: name,
  sequence: asc
}
```

So I'd like to do something like this:

```
var url = location.search;
url = url.replace('?', '');
var queries = url.split('&');
var params = {};
for(var q in queries) {
var param = queries[q].split('=');
params.param[0] = param[1];
```

};

But this line:

```
params.param[0] = param[1]
```

generates an error. How do you iterate through those keys if you don't know the key names?

We're using jQuery, and I'm sure there's a plugin to do this, but I'd like to understand how to program this anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
params[ param[0] ] = param[1]
```

FYI, you could use a [regex approach](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/06/10/reading-get-variables-with-javascript/) too.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [URL Utils jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-url-utils-plugin/), it does precisely this!

`var params = $.queryString();`